How to get first multiple entry Schengen visa
I have 3 single visas in approximately 2 years.
Now I want to apply for MEV (multiple entry visa),
How Should I write my cover letter to ask for 1 year MEV?
What is more possibile duration that they will give me the MEV?

It depends on the reason (visit, job, etc.) and what are next plans. So maybe we go too much in details for us to answer appropriately.

The phrasing makes it sounds like the goal is the MEV, not the trip(s). That is a red flag.

Visa shopping (which is what that is) is very very badly seen in Schengen

I’m not sure why this looks like visa shopping given it’s not the OP’s first Schengen visa. Getting a long term MEV is obviously something many travellers would aspire to, and the rules actually require an applicant to have had a set number of visas previously. The OP has already visited Spain and The Netherlands, neither of which are particularly ‘easy’ to get a visa for, and while a repeat visit to one of these might make sense, choosing another destination on the basis of the likelihood of success seems as logical to me as choosing one for eg its food/culture.


I want to apply for MEV (multiple entry visa), which country do you suggest? Netherlands or Spain?
Or a new country?

Data on short-stay visas issued by Schengen countries for 2023 is available here and you can also view it by the country from which the applications were made (i.e., by consulate).
As others have commented, the way your question is phrased suggests that you might be visa shopping, which is frowned upon. I recommend you choose your destination based first on where you would most like to visit, and not on which looks like the easiest to get, in order to avoid giving a bad impression in your application.

How Should I write my cover letter to ask for 1 year MEV?

See How do I ask for a long validity Schengen visa?

I am interested in both countries to visit more and more. With a single entry visa you are limited to a specific time,the process of requesting and getting your visa is too long, you should apply 3 months before your trip. If you have a long term  and multiple entry visa you can plan your trips more flexible. Some countries issue their visa multiple and long term like Canada.
